# Function parallelization Python

Tags: sql, python-3.x, parallel-processing, bioinformatics, biopython

The objective of my code is to do some calculations over a xml files given by a bioinformatic software called biopython. This program generates an iterator that looks like this:

```
blast_records
<generator object parse at 0x00000174AFB21390>
```

With each element of the iterator, I do some calculations and upload the result to a mysql database. When I call the element looks like this:

```
<Bio.Blast.Record.Blast object at 0x00000174AF383E80>
```

My code is as follows:

```
from Bio.Blast import NCBIXML
import pymysql
result_handle = open(*file*)
blast_records = NCBIXML.parse(result_handle)

*start sql connection

def calculation(blast_record):
      # do calculation
      # upload to sql

for blast record in blast_records:
    calculation(blast_record)
```

I've tried to parallelize it with tools like joblib and multiprocessing using a list comprehension similar to this:

```
processes = [mp.Process(target=calculation, args=(blast_record)) for blast_record in blast_records]
```

But with **`joblib`** I got the error: PicklingError: Could not pickle the task to send it to the workers

And with **`multiprocessing`** the code runs indefinitely

Any help in how to structure my code for parallelize each input of the function?

Comment: There are known limitations of the default SER/DES via `pickle.dumps()` yet some might get circumvented by a more capable pickler - read about **`dill`**-module from Mike McKearns ( which used to pickle in a bit smarter way, and could even traverse some more complicated class-instances, yet always depends on actual use-case ) and one may trick the game of `joblib`-based attempts to harness the multiprocessing via **`import dill as pickle`** Try it to test this immediately available and the most straightforward way, before starting any more and more expensive re-factoring strategy

Comment: Give us some example data please :) It might be that we can help, but it is hard to tell without knowing what your data looks like :)